# PHP how to output error message from remote gateway after executing bash script

Tags: php, bash

I have a simple PHP function that will make a call to a remote gateway base on the radio button option the user selects and submits to call a script (up.sh or down.sh). I am able to successfully run the script from the remote gateway, however, whenever something goes wrong my webpage doesn't show the error. Is there a way to echo the error on the webpage?

testexe.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){    
  //create the ssh connection
      if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
           ssh2_auth_password($connection, $gwUser, $gwPwd);
           if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/home/user/aust/up.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo '<pre>' . stream_get_contents($stream_out) . '</pre>';

           }

           if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/home/user/aust/down.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo '<pre>' . stream_get_contents($stream_out) . '</pre>';
           }
     }
}
```

up.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'expect -f ./scripts/myExpectScript.exp' //I can see this on the webpage
expect -f ./scripts/myExpectScript.exp //this throws an error but i dont see the error on the page.
echo
```

error output:

```
expect -f ./scripts/myExpectScript.exp
couldn't read file "./scripts/myExpectScript.exp": no such file or directory //I want to see this on the webpage.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the flag `SSH2_STREAM_STDIO` which should give you a result when things work as expected. If there is a problem I believe you need the flag `SSH2_STREAM_STDERR`.

See `ssh2_fetch_stream`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-fetch-stream.php

And `SSH2_STREAM_STDERR` on Predefined Constants: http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.constants.php

Comment: perfect, also one last thing is there a way to output both the SSH2_STREAM_STDIO and SSH2_STREAM_STDIO?

Comment: Appears you can only request one at a time. If you know there will be output but nothing was returned from `SSH2_STREAM_STDIO` then you could check `SSH2_STREAM_STDERR`. Otherwise you could skip checking both every time.